# prove that $p(n) := n^2 + n + c$ is not prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, proof-writing, computer-science

The question is in MIT Mathematics for CS assignments but unfortunately there is no solutions.

-> I do understand that it is false if we use $n = c$ or $n = c-1$ but cannot formally write it as expected in the problem like what would be the different if $c$ is prime or not ?

For $n = 40$, the value of polynomial $p(n) := n^2 + n + 41$ is not prime, as noted in Chapter 1 of the Course Text. But we could have predicted based on general principles that no nonconstant polynomial, $q(n)$, with integer coefficients can map each nonnegative integer into a prime number. Prove it.
Hint: Let $c := q(0)$ be the constant term of $q$. Consider two cases: c is not prime, and $c$ is prime. In the second case, note that $q(cn)$ is a multiple of $c$ for all $n \in Z$. You may assume the familiar fact that the magnitude (absolute value) of any nonconstant polynomial, $q(n)$, grows unboundedly as $n$ grows.

Comment: I assume that $c$ is an integer. For $c = 41$, your get a composite number if you set $n = 40$. Can you generalize that trick?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought about that for any n=c the proposition is false but I don't think that is the solution required.

Comment: Note that the problem isn't specifically talking about the polynomial $n^2+n+c$; it talks about _all_ polynomials.

Comment: What does the assignment say: ¨ Show that that given $c$, $n^2 + n + c$ is never prime"? That is false. Or: "Show that for any given $c$ there is $n$ such that $n^2 + n + c$ is not prime"? That is a true statement.

Comment: In fact, the question is somewhat deceptive - it doesn't matter whether $c$ is prime or not; the key distinction is between $|c|\neq 1$ and $|c|=1$.(why doesn't $|c|=0$ matter?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $q(0)$ is not prime, then you're done: you have a value at which the polynomial is not prime.

If $c = q(0)$ is prime, then since $q$ is not constant, we may write
$$q(n) = c + np(n),$$
where $p(n)$ is a non-zero polynomial. Therefore,
$$q(cn) = c + cnp(cn) = c(1 + np(cn)),$$
which confirms the hint: $q(cn)$ is divisible by $c$. Therefore, if $q(cn)$ is always prime, then it is always $c$, which is to say that, for all $n$,
$$1 + np(cn) = 1 \iff np(cn) = 0.$$
But $np(cn)$ is a non-zero polynomial, with finitely many roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra. So $np(cn) = 0$ for only finitely many $n$ (or maybe none at all), which is a contradiction.

Comment: I understand most of the proof but I can't understand why since c is prime and q isn't constant we can write q(n)=c+np(n) ? is np(n) equivalent to n(n+1) ?

Comment: This is a general proof for any polynomial, not just for polynomials in the form $c + n + n^2$. But, in that case, yes $np(n)$ is just $n(n + 1)$.

Comment: Also, sorry for not being clear, but we can write any non-constant polynomial $q(x)$ as $q(x) = q(0) + xp(x)$ for some polynomial $p(x)$. Just think about an arbitrary polynomial $q(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n$. Then $q(0) = a_0$, so we can write, $q(x) = q(0) + x(a_1 + a_2 x + \ldots + a_n x^{n-1})$. In this general case, $p(x) = a_1 + a_2 x + \ldots + a_n x^{n-1}$.

Comment: This answer falls down in the case where $c=\pm 1$ and a slightly more extended argument is needed to cover that.

Comment: Read the question again: if $c = \pm 1$, then we certainly do not have a polynomial that maps each non-negative integer to a prime because it does not map $0$ to a prime.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki isn't at c =1 , it is not a prime number ?

Comment: @TheoBendit Ahhh, good point - I'd missed the obvious there; thank you.